How to Prevent CircularProgressIndicator from freezing during Authentication in Kotlin Compose?
I have a Kotlin Compose app that allows users to authenticate with Facebook and Google. During the login process, a CircularProgressIndicator is displayed and spins until the user's account creation and login are completed. However, the CircularProgressIndicator freezes for a few seconds, it looks like the app is blocked. I suspect this is due to thread management issues, as the login process runs on a separate thread.
Does anyone have suggestions on how to keep the CircularProgressIndicator running smoothly without any interruptions? Should I consider placing it on a dedicated thread?
This how I do the google login:
@Composable
fun activityGoogleResultLauncher(): ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> {
    val loginViewModel = LocalUserState.current
    val startAutocomplete: ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> = rememberLauncherForActivityResult(
        contract = ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()
    ) { result ->
        val completedTask: Task<GoogleSignInAccount> =
            GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(result.data)
        try {
            if (completedTask.isSuccessful) {
                val account: GoogleSignInAccount? =
                    completedTask.getResult(ApiException::class.java)
                val email = account?.email
                val token: String = account?.idToken!!
                runBlocking {
                    loginViewModel.singInWithGoogle(token)
                    loginViewModel.getUserType = true
                    loginViewModel.loginStatus = "in"
                    FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().token.addOnCompleteListener {
                        loginViewModel.insertFCMWhenLogin(it.result)
                    }
                    if (email != null) {
                        loginViewModel.updateEmail(email)
                    }
                }
            } else {
                println("AUTH Google Auth failed: ${completedTask.exception}")
            }
        } catch (e: ApiException) {
            println("AUTH Failed to authenticate using Google OAuth: " + e.message)
        }
    }
    return startAutocomplete
}

And for Facebook it is this:
LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(
    callbackManager,
    object : FacebookCallback<LoginResult> {
        override fun onSuccess(result: LoginResult) {
            val accessToken = result.accessToken
            coroutineScope.launch {
                loginViewModel.signInWithFacebookLogin(accessToken.token)
                loginViewModel.getUserType = true
                loginViewModel.loginStatus = "in"
                FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().token.addOnCompleteListener {
                    loginViewModel.insertFCMWhenLogin(it.result)
                }
            }
        }

        override fun onCancel() {
            println("AUTH Cancelled Facebook login")
            loginViewModel.loadingLogin = false
        }

        override fun onError(error: FacebookException) {
            println("AUTH Failed to authenticate with Facebook: ${error.message}")
            loginViewModel.loadingLogin = false
        }
    },
)

This is the insertFCMWhenLogin function:
fun insertFCMWhenLogin(token: String) {
    viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        try {
            repo.insertFCMWhenLogin(token)
        } catch (exp: Exception) {
            println("FCM token error")
        }
    }
}


I reverted your last edit. Please do not fundamentally change the question after it was answered. Ask a new question instead. That said, StackOverflow wouldn't be the right place to ask this kind of thing anyways, that would be much better suited for the sister site [codereview.se]. They have a different focus on what is ontopic, so make sure you read their How to Ask page first.

Could you review it please? https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/292290/kotlin-compose-authentication-with-google-and-facebook-using-a-circularprogressi?noredirect=1#comment581632_292290

I told you in the previous comment that the requirements on [codereview.se] are different from StackOverflow and that you should read their How to Ask page. Despite that you already received two comments complaining about the question's quality where you ignored the first one: "This is missing complete, runnable code." Also you posted the same question twice after it was ill-received. Please don't just ignore all the feedback you get, act on it and improve your questions according to the respective requirements.

How I am supposed to put all the code in one ticket, you don't need the full repo in order to make a review, don't understand what is wrong with the ticket.

No, only what's relevant, the part that you want reviewed. Make sure that part is complete and runnable.

It's impossible to run Facebook login in mobile without api keys and secrets. For google is even harder without a google play release. :(

Then mock it with something adequate that won't distort what you want to ask. That said, the comments are not the place to have an extended conversation. Everything you need was already said, most of it even multiple times.

You are using runBlocking to be able to use loginViewModel functions. This is probably the reason why you are getting some lag on the UI. ViewModels should not expose suspend functions.
For example, if you have this in your ViewModel:
suspend fun signInWithFacebookLogin() {
    
    // Async func
    
}

Change it to this:
fun signInWithFacebookLogin() {
    
    viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {

        // Async func
        
    }

}


Could you please check the updated code? It is the best version? Thanks for the help so far!

I see you are still calling loginViewModel.signInWithFacebookLogin() from another coroutine. If you are already using viewModelScope for this function and it isn't suspend, you don't require a coroutine anymore.
Also, you can update getUserType and loginStatus within signInWithFacebookLogin(), so there's no need to do it outside the viewModel in this case.
This way, you won't need to use coroutines outside the viewModel for this. When login is done and you have the data you need, update the uiState from your viewModel and your UI should react to this.

Could you review it please: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/292290/kotlin-compose-authentication-with-google-and-facebook-using-a-circularprogressi?noredirect=1#comment581632_292290

The CircularProgressIndicator runs on the main thread. If that is blocked for longer than a frame then the indicator starts to stutter or even comes to a halt like you experience it.
The solution is to make the login procedure main-safe. Your question makes conflicting statements about it already running in a separate thread, but even without having the actual code to look at I'm pretty sure it doesn't. I guess you just launch that in a new coroutine.
That is good, but it is not sufficient. Launching it in a new coroutine makes it run asynchronous to the indicator, so they take turns running on the same thread. That will work just fine if the coroutine suspends every so often so that the indicator also gets a slice of the main thread at least every frame. From what you describe that doesn't seem to be the case, though.
Now, you have two ways to approach this:

Make the coroutine suspend when it isn't doing anything, like waiting for a network request to finish. That all depends on how your login procedure actually works, so I'm not sure that it would be as easy as just calling yield().
Move the coroutine to another thread. In Kotlin you usually doesn't handle threads yourself, instead you delegate that to a dispatcher. There are three preconfigured dispatchers you can use: Dispatchers.Main for the main thread (that's what your coroutine is currently using), Dispatchers.Default for CPU intensive operations and Dispatchers.IO for anything filesystem or network related. The latter seems to be the one you need to use. You can switch to another dispatcher either directly when launching the coroutine with launch(Dispatchers.IO) { ... } or at a later time in any suspend function by wrapping the code that should be moved to another thread in withContext(Dispatchers.IO) { ... }. By doing this you instruct the coroutine to use a thread of the IO dispatcher instead of using the thread from the main dispatcher.

Implementing at least one of the above will make your coroutine main-safe, that is, it will be safe to be called on the main thread without it interfering with other UI operations like updating your CircularProgressIndicator. It should run smoothly now.

To address the edit to the question:
The Facebook login seems fine so far, but for the Google Login you call runBlocking. Well, that does exactly what it says: It blocks the current thread to run its lambda. So no further updates to CircularProgressIndicator until that lambda is completed. If that isn't what you want then just remove it. Actually, in an Android app you will probably never have a valid use case to use runBlocking, so please forget that it even exists.
If you just need a coroutine scope to launch a coroutine so you can call suspend functions in it you can get one in Compose like this:
val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()

But I don't see why you would even need this: You only access the view model (which should never expose any suspend functions since it has a built-in viewModelScope) and the Firebase API which should only be accessed by the view model. You can take a look at the Codelab for Firebase in Compose to get some pointers how this should look like.

I have updated the question with the specific code, could you have a look again please and tell me what I have to change. Thanks for the help.
